# How to generate cross section from the boundary of a 3D point cloud?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision

I had a number of raw 3d points and a boundary for it, as well as the indices for those points on the boundary surface. As shown in the figure:

[Left: Raw data points and its boundary; Right: points on the boundary surface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lpjw.png)

I want to make cross sections out of the boundary surface, at a different angle. How should I do this?

I looked at varies ways to make cross sections, including 2D interpolation and 3d contour plot for meshgrids, but none of them work since the point cloud is not a meshgrid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of application that will generate an approximating mesh from a point cloud. Geomagic Wrap may be the easiest to use.